# Mysql Database design - checklist/quiz application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm currently 'learning' codeigniter, php and mySql all at once as I try and create a "checklist" type of website, where visitors sign up, create a project and are asked a list of questions, where they must input certain fields

I'm a little stuck on my mySQL DB-design... (completely stuck actually)

what it comes down to is...

1 project can have one of 3 types. "type a/b/c"

**Type a** has 20 questions

**Type b** = type a + 15 questions

**Type c** = type b + 15 questions...

So basically I'd like to be able to easily say, Question A is **Type A** AND/OR **Type B** but **not C**.

Now, I don't know if what I'm doing is correct, but I'm basically making two tables and then setting a relationship between them "many to many" (i think?) **n:m in mySQL workbench**

```
ProjectType
id
ProjectTypeName

Questions
ID
Title etc...

ProjectType_has_Questions
ProjectType_id
Questions_id
```

---

Also, every question "CAN, not must" have 3 results (current facts) and 3 corrections (improvement on results).

I don't know if this is making any sense to anyone here, sure as hell is baffeling me :-/

any thoughts?

ps: I tried to attach an image but seeing as this is my first time using the site this wasn't allowed.

Comment: Do questions have types or is it just projects that have types? Your sketched schema only seems to have project types. If questions do not have types, what do you mean by *Question A is Type A*?

Comment: A few things are unclear.  Can users define their own project, or do they just choose answers to questions in a few predefined types of projects?  What is a "current fact" and an "improvement on results"?

Comment: Let me try to clarify...

I'm trying to create a list comparable to http://www.launchlist.com but then more focused on SEO rules.

So a user would sign up, and then be offered a list he has to fill in.

There will be three types of lists, which must be chosen at the start of the project.

I think John @ cashcommons's 'flexible' answer, where I create a linking table is the way to go?

So I'd create a table where all the questions go, then a table where the question groups go, and finally I create a table where I assign groups to a question.

http://alturl.com/ve8y3 - img of my DB EER Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll respond to what I understand here.  Had a few other questions that I commented on in your question.

If your project types will always aggregate -- that is, Type C is always a superset of Type B, which is always a superset of Type A -- then for the questions you can just specify the biggest project that that particular question will be included in.  Say, if a question will appear in Types A and B, then designate the question as Type B.  If it will appear in all three types, designate it as Type C.

You're committing yourself when you do this, though.  A more flexible way to do this would be to have a linking table that includes the question ID and the project type ID.  Each question can have one or more entries in this table.